# Laravel 5 mock PasswordBroker

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, mockery

From the boilerplate `PasswordController::postEmail()` I'm trying to mock (using `Mockery`) this part:

```
// $this->password is an instance of PasswordBroker
$response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function($m)
    {
        $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    });
```

In my test case, I'm calling `->shouldReceive('sendResetLink')->with($postData, ???)`

Since this is a closure, I'm sure I have to pass a closure, and also mock the `$m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());` but I am blank on this one, as I'm relatively new to TDD.

Can I get some directions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
->shouldReceive('sendResetLink')
->once()
->with($postData, \Mockery::type('Closure'));
```